# DataGridControl.Resources DataCell EventSetter alternative

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, nant, xceed-datagrid

I have code in my `Xceed DataGridControl Resources` where i hookup on the `PreviewKeyDown`event.

This code works and build fine on my colleagues and my laptop. But when our deployment team tries to build this with `Nant` it generates following error:

```
.xaml(141,17): error BC30469: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference. 
.g.vb(191,17): error BC30108: 'eventSetter' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.
```

This is the code in the Xaml file:

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>

                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataCell}">
                        <EventSetter Event="PreviewKeyDown"
                                     Handler="CellPreviewKeyDown" />
                    </Style>
                </xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>
```

Is there a way to attach to this event in any other way?
Or is there a way how i can solve this problem with `Nant`?

I have tried using some framework to bind the event to a command but then i loose my current DataCell as aregument and i need it to trigger the `EndEdit` event.